# Did the Duchess steal the $50,000 at the butler's gay party?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

Who stole the money at the butler's gay party?

There is no further explanation is given as to who stole the money. The interrogation scene doesn't explain it either.

Could it be that the Duchess did it?

Comment: It was Nicolas, he just wouldn't admit it.

Comment: @Paulie_D - There were 21 other people in the apartment and bedroom on the night that the cash went missing. That's an awful lot of suspects. Frankly, Nicolas is not high on the list of suspects.

Answer (score 10):

Patrick (Nicholas in the film), or more likely one of his 'guests', probably stole the money. In the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book)) by Jordan Belfort we learn that the butler hosted an orgy with ***21***(!) guests. All of them were in and out of the bedroom and literally any one of them could have taken the money.

> It wasn’t long after that that the shit hit the fan. Patrick the
> Butler made the sad mistake of assuming that the Duchess would be
> joining me at my parents’ house for Passover dinner, so he decided to
> host a gay orgy for twenty-one of his friends, who formed a human
> daisy chain around my living room and then played naked Twister in my
> bedroom. Yes, it was quite a sight the Duchess (who was twenty-three
> at the time) had the pleasure of walking in to: all those homosexuals
> pressed together—butt to nut—rutting away like barnyard animals in our
> tiny Manhattan love nest, on the fifty-third floor of Olympic Towers.
>
> It was from out the window of that very floor, in fact, that Victor
> ended up hanging Patrick the Butler, after it came to light that
> Patrick and his posse had stolen $50,000 in cash from my sock drawer.
> In Victor’s defense, though, he hung Patrick out the window only after
> he’d asked him repeated times to return the stolen goods. Of course,
> his requests were punctuated by right crosses and left hooks, which
> had the effect of breaking Patrick’s nose, rupturing the capillaries
> in both his eyes, and cracking three or four of his ribs. You would’ve
> thought Patrick would come clean and return the stolen money, wouldn’t
> you?
>
> Well, he didn’t. In fact, Danny and I were there to witness Victor’s
> act of savagery. It was Danny, more than anyone, who’d been talking
> tough—up until Victor threw the first punch and Patrick’s face
> exploded into raw hamburger meat, at which time Danny ran to the
> bathroom and began vomiting.
>
> After a while it seemed that Victor was getting a bit carried away and
> was on the verge of dropping Patrick out the window. So I kindly asked
> Victor to pull him back in, a request that seemed to deeply sadden
> Victor but that he followed nonetheless. When Danny emerged from the
> bathroom, looking worried and green, I explained to him that I had
> called the cops and they were coming to arrest Patrick the Butler.
> Danny was absolutely stunned that I would have the audacity to call
> the police after being the architect of Patrick’s assault. But, again,
> I explained that when the police arrived I would tell them exactly
> what had happened, which was what I did. And to ensure that the two
> young policeman fully got my meaning, I gave each of them a thousand
> dollars in cash, at which point they nodded, removed their nightsticks
> from their NYPD utility belts, and began beating the shit out of
> Patrick the Butler all over again.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Wolf of Wall Street by Jordan Belfort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book))</sup></sub>

It's highly unlikely The Duchess stole it; She was the one who reported it missing and had she asked nicely, Jordan would have happily given her some spending money. This is a woman who'd just spent $120k of his cash on a rug and $64k on new silk bedding. She didn't need to steal money from him.

Comment: "*She didn't need to steal money from him.*": sometimes, need isn't the motive; you would be surprised by how rich people can steal, from small things to big amount of money, for reasons only a psychiatrist could explain. It might not be that important, but I was shocked when I learnt this.

Comment: @OldPadawan - Sure, but it's basically her money. She can get it whenever she needs it, in quantities greater than this. Reporting it as stolen to Jordan doesn't serve any useful purpose other than to implicate the butler, who she doesn't seem to have had any specific animus toward, other than not being especially pleased to have found in a gay orgy in her apartment.

Comment: Source *novel* is right. If you believe a convicted fraudster that there was a party where 21 people had sex with each other simultaneously, then I have a bridge to sell you.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - I gather some saunas host events for *hundreds* of willing orgy participants. Getting twenty of them back to a fancy apartment should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: @Valorum - What *could* have happened and what did happen are likely two very different things, particularly with a serial and even *convicted* liar. It seems eminently plausible to me that a few people having sex became "21 people had sex at the same time in a circle." A person who had known him at the time said that the book had only a distant relationship to reality, and mentioned a few things that he did know to be true (not including the alleged orgy).

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Oh, sure. I guess like all good books written by larger-than-life characters like Belfort, there's probably bits that he's embellished, bits he's invented and bits that are true but that he's left out because nobody would believe them.